# Saving/Loading Config Not Working

Tags: java

First time posting here. Heres my problem: I can't get the saving or loading of my configuration file to work. I am trying to save player names based off how many players specified in my code. Anyone know what is wrong and how to fix? 
Config file:

```
public void savePlayerConfiguration(String key, int value) {
    String path = "config.xml";
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        boolean exists = file.exists();
        if (!exists) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        OutputStream write = new FileOutputStream(path);
        properties.setProperty(key, Integer.toString(value));
        properties.storeToXML(write, key);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public void loadPlayerConfiguration(String path) {
    try {
        InputStream read = new FileInputStream(path);
        properties.loadFromXML(read);
        String player1 = properties.getProperty("1");
        String player2 = properties.getProperty("2");
        String player3 = properties.getProperty("3");
        String player4 = properties.getProperty("4");
        String player5 = properties.getProperty("5");
        String player6 = properties.getProperty("6");
        read.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        savePlayerConfiguration("1", 1);
        savePlayerConfiguration("2", 2);
        savePlayerConfiguration("3", 3);
        savePlayerConfiguration("4", 4);
        savePlayerConfiguration("5", 5);
        savePlayerConfiguration("6", 6);
        loadConfiguration(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

Options file:

```
 private int width = Main.width;
private int height = Main.height;

private String player1 = "Player1", player2 = "Player2",
        player3 = "Player3", player4 = "Player4", player5 = "Player5",
        player6 = "Player6";
private String[] playerNames = { player1, player2, player3, player4,
        player5, player6 };
private int[] player = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
private int playerTotal;
private JButton OK;
private JTextField input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6;
private JTextField[] playerNameInput = { input1, input2, input3, input4,
        input5, input6 };
private JLabel playerName;
private Rectangle rOK, rPlayerAmount;
private Choice playerAmount = new Choice();
Configuration config = new Configuration();

private int button_width = 80;
private int button_height = 40;

JPanel window = new JPanel();

public Database() {
    setTitle("Database - Excelteor Launcher");
    setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    add(window);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    window.setLayout(null);
    drop();

    drawButtons();
    window.repaint();
}

private void drawButtons() {
    OK = new JButton("OK");
    rOK = new Rectangle((width - 100), (height - 70), button_width,
            button_height);
    OK.setBounds(rOK);
    window.add(OK);

    rPlayerAmount = new Rectangle(30, 130, 80, 25);
    playerAmount.setBounds(rPlayerAmount);
    playerAmount.add("1");
    playerAmount.add("2");
    playerAmount.add("3");
    playerAmount.add("4");
    playerAmount.add("5");
    playerAmount.add("6");
    playerAmount.select(1);
    window.add(playerAmount);

    playerName = new JLabel("Player Names:");
    playerName.setBounds(30, 110, 120, 20);
    window.add(playerName);

    for (int i = 0; i < playerTotal; i++) {
        playerNameInput[i] = new JTextField();
        playerNameInput[i].setBounds(80, 150 + i * 20, 60, 20);
        window.add(playerNameInput[i]);
    }

    OK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
            System.out.println("test");
            for (int i = 0; i < playerTotal; i++) {
                config.savePlayerConfiguration(parsePlayers(), player[i]);
                System.out.println(player[i]);
            }
        }
    });

}

private void drop() {
    int selection = playerAmount.getSelectedIndex();
    if (selection == 0) {
        playerTotal = 1;
    }
    if (selection == 1 || selection == -1) {
        playerTotal = 2;
    }
    if (selection == 2) {
        playerTotal = 3;
    }
    if (selection == 3) {
        playerTotal = 4;
    }
    if (selection == 4) {
        playerTotal = 5;
    }
    if (selection == 5) {
        playerTotal = 6;
    }

}

private String parsePlayers() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < playerTotal; i++) {
            playerNames[i] = playerNameInput[i].toString();
            return playerNames[i];
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        drop();
        return player1;
    }
    return player1;
}
```

Comment: [commons configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration//userguide/howto_properties.html) might be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the path of your config.xml, the one being passed into loadPlayerConfiguration(String path), is wrong. Try out the below options for resolving your problem.

1. Make sure that the 'path' is correct.
2. Make sure that the 'path' exists using exists() method of File API.
3. If the path is relative, then confirm whether the path structure has been added onto the 
   class path. Else, try placing it in the root of your project.

If you still face issues after trying out these steps, then kindly share your project structure.

Cheers,
Madhu.

** EDIT **
@user2399785 : got a clear idea on your problem after going through your config.xml.

```
<properties>
<comment>javax.swing.JTextField[,80,150,60x20,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@69ecade2,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]</comment>
<entry key="javax.swing.JTextField[,80,150,60x20,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@69ecade2,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]">2</entry>
<entry key="javax.swing.JTextField[,80,150,60x20,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@2904a7cf,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]">2</entry>
</properties>
```

If you notice your .xml, the KEY contains some kind of a long javax swing detail. But loadPlayerConfiguration(String path) uses `properties.getProperty("2")` which will return you a VALUE whose KEY is "2" and not vice versa. Since there is no KEY with "2", you are getting the return value as NULL. Try the same code with the KEY as in the .xml and you should be fine.

Cheers,
Madhu.

Comment: It is the correct path. The classes are in the same package too.

Comment: Couldnt Get it to work :( I've updated a lot of stuff before I saw you commented back, so if you look back on the github maybe you can see what is wrong now? Thanks for any help....

Comment: @user2399785 : that's bad. but it worked for me when I tried with your code snippet.